# Convert numeric string to Roman numeral

Tags: strings, roman-numerals

I have a (sub)string (not a counter) which consists of an Arabic number. Is there an easy to convert this string to a Roman numeral? I suppose I could build an array of sorts, but I think this would become tiresome quickly. I am using `LuaLaTeX`, so a line or two of Lua code would be fine, too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\myString{9}

\begin{document}

How can I have \myString read "IX" instead of 9?

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\MakeUppercase{\romannumeral\myString\relax}`

Comment: The “substring” reference seems to make this an XY question.

Comment: @egreg: I don't understand. Ulrike's solution works very well, though. It's simple and elegant. (Probably should be a full answer.)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to change the meaning of `\myString` to be the Roman numeral representation:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\makeRoman}{om}
 {% #1 = optional control sequence
  % #2 = something that expands to a positive integer
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
   {
    \tl_set:Nx #2 { \int_to_Roman:n { #2 } }
   }
   {
    \tl_clear_new:N #1
    \tl_set:Nx #1 { \int_to_Roman:n { #2 } }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\myString{9}

\makeRoman{\myString}

\makeRoman[\newString]{7*5-4}

\begin{document}

How can I have \myString\ read "IX" instead of 9?

Also \newString\  works.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you just want to print something that expands to a positive integers in Roman numerals:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\printRoman}{m}
 {
  \int_to_Roman:n { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\myString{9}

\begin{document}

It works, see? Here \printRoman{\myString} works.

\end{document}
```

[image]

You *might* do `\MakeUppercase{\romannumeral\myString}`, but it wouldn't be expandable, so only useful for printing the number, not for feeding the Roman numeral representation to something else.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and your sample code, I'll bear that in mind. Luckily it's really just to print the number once, as part of a heading, which is why the “primitive”‌ approach suits me fine.

Answer (score 4):

Use the package `modroman`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{modroman}

\begin{document}

How can I have \nbRoman{9} read "IX" instead of 9?

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you for a perfectly viable solution, even though I'd rather not use another package.

Comment: Before expl3 is written, people make many packages to do miscellaneous simple tasks, and efforts (might be) duplicated. Nowadays the package remains

Comment: I've used `modroman` for years, but I admit that I haven't recently checked whether it was still really required or not. The thing is, I largely prefer loading a package rather than bloating my class file with code snippets... Thanks, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 4):

Here are two ways (the first one being essentially the same as in [Ulrike Fischer's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/651474/convert-numeric-string-to-roman-numeral/651479#comment1623779_651474)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\myNine{9}

\begin{document}

\MakeUppercase{\romannumeral \myNine\space}~plus
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_to_Roman:n { \myNine } \nobreakspace
equals \nobreakspace
\int_to_Roman:n { \myNine + \myNine }.
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\space` after `\romannumeral \myNine` expands to a space token that finishes the ⟨number⟩. `\romannumeral` is a TeX primitive that reads a ⟨number⟩, and ⟨number⟩ has ⟨one optional space⟩ in its grammar rules when the number is specified using character tokens representing the digits; the optional space token is part of the ⟨number⟩ and tells TeX that the number is complete at this point. These precautions are not necessary when using  `\int_to_Roman:n` (which accepts an `expl3` ⟨integer expression⟩ as a normal, i.e. braced argument).

Comment: Very useful, but certainly does more than I need … Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! :-)

Answer (score 3):

A combination of `\romannumeral` and a `\directlua` call:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\myString{9}
\newcommand\IngmarRomanNumeral[1]{%
   \directlua{tex.sprint(string.upper('\romannumeral #1'))}}
   
\begin{document}
\romannumeral5, \romannumeral\myString

\IngmarRomanNumeral{5}, \IngmarRomanNumeral{\myString}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Who knew there would be so many ways to skin the cat, so to speak …

Comment: Beware of things like `\romannumeral\myString 1 foobar`... which may or may not yield what you expect. :)

Comment: Duly noted. My code is trivial, and the Roman numeral is part of a heading, so if anything were off it would catch my eye quickly. In this case, luckily, there's zero chance of this coming back to bite me further down the line.

Comment: @frougon - While `\romannumeral\myString 1 foobar` will indeed create a unanticipated result, that's not the case for `\IngmarRomanNumeral{\myString} 1 foobar`. (I sure hope that it's clear that the argument of `\IngmarRomanNumeral` should be enclosed in curly braces.) :-)

Comment: @Mico Yes, I only wrote this for the line after `\begin{document}` to make sure non-TeXperts don't get trapped by `\romannumeral`'s behavior. :-)